# How can I get multiple elements from an array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

How can I get multiple elements from an array at once that satisfy a specific condition, for example: `Date <= 2020-12-31`. I read about `$elemMatch`, but I can only get one specific element with it.

```
"someArray": [
            {
                "Date": "2021-09-30",
                "value": "6.62"
            },
            {
                "Date": "2020-12-31",
                "value": "8.67"
            },
            {
                "Date": "2019-12-31",
                "value": "12.81"
            },
            {
                "Date": "2018-12-31",
                "value": "13.82"
            },
            {
                "Date": "2017-12-31",
                "value": "13.83"
            },
            ...
            ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$filter` in an aggregation query like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "someArray": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$someArray",
          "as": "a",
          "cond": {
            "$lte": [
              "$$a.Date",
              ISODate("2020-12-31")
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aiHYxJ1f5fL)

Note that you can use `$project` or `$set` (available since version 4.2): [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yNHAa36eEMc) or `$addFields`: [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JoTFlPzKBBI)

Comment: Thank you, it helped me! And how can I add another condition, for example, Data >= 2017-12-31?

Comment: Use `$and` to add multiple conditions into `cond`. Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9IJioNe6bY6)